# How to refactor round method with 3 digits

Tags: ruby

I would like to round float numbers like this :

```
125.212 = 125.250
125.249 = 125.250
125.268 = 125.250
125.280 = 125.275
125.999 = 126.000
```

I have do a method, how can I refactor it ?

```
def round_km(n)
    n = n * 1000
    m = n % 100
    if (m <= 25)
        "%.3f" % ((n - m + 25) / 1000).round(3)
    elsif (m <= 50)
        "%.3f" % ((n - m + 50) / 1000).round(3)
    elsif (m <= 75)
        "%.3f" % ((n - m + 75) / 1000).round(3)
    else
        "%.3f" % ((n - m + 100) / 1000).round(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: What does "factorise" mean here? Do you mean "refactor"? The only thing that changes is the value you're adding to `n - m` so that'd be the refactor. Unrelated: rounding 125.212 up to 125.250 seems like a bad idea given the rest of the rules.

Comment: Can you explain this using set notation? I don't understand your rounding scheme

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution :

```
  def round_km(n)
    "%.3f" % ((n/0.250).ceil * 0.250)
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't meet your stated requirements; it rounds `125.280` to `125.500`.